# Rails precompiling error (invalid UTF-8 byte sequence)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, precompile

I accidentally put a js file in assets/images and now heroku won't let me precompile my assets even after I deleted the js file.

Here's the error message I got

```
AssetSync: YAML file found /tmp/build_326asn5xl82tm/config/asset_sync.yml settings will be merged into the configuration
       rake aborted!
       /tmp/build_326asn5xl82tm/app/assets/images/images/index_solid.js has a invalid UTF-8 byte sequence
       /tmp/build_326asn5xl82tm/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/utils.rb:19:in `block (2 levels) in read_unicode'
```

Comment: You should try to empty your /tmp/ directory

Comment: I've tried. Still received the same error message

Answer (score 0):

Try going into the Heroku bash and deleting the file using rm.

```
heroku run bash
```

Comment: I tried. It says No such file or directory. I deleted the file everywhere in the application folder but the error is still here.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple options that you could look at.  Errors like this are generally due to a non-ASCII character being in the yaml file (like Ñ).

I think I remember running this error, and I ended up just deleting the non ASCII characters.  In the js file.

Errors like this can sometimes be solved by installing the `magic_encoding` gem and using `# encoding: utf-8` at the top of the file.  However I don't think it would work given the error